# Resonance integral in LCAO method for homonuclear biatomic molecules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, molecules

In LCAO method for approximate solutions to Schrodinger equation of homonuclear diatomic molecules, it is defined an integral called "resonance integral" whose expression is:
$$
\beta = \langle\Psi_{a}|\Psi_{b}\rangle = \int \Psi_{a}^*(\vec{x}) \Psi_{b}(\vec{x})\, \mathrm{d}^3x
$$

Why is it called $\textit{resonance}$ integral?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an accident of history and actually not very interesting. The word resonance refers to the concept of [Lewis resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_(chemistry)) used in chemistry.

Note that the expression you give is the overlap integral not the resonance integral. The resonance integral is:

$$ H_{ab} = \int \Psi_{a}^* \hat{H} \Psi_{b}\, \mathrm{d}^3x $$

And it describes (in an arm waving sort of way) the interaction between the atomic orbitals on two different atoms. Typically the interaction will be written as a sum of all the interactions between all the different atomic orbitals:

$$ H = \int \left(\sum_i a_i^*\psi_i^*\right) \,\hat{H} \left(\sum_j a_j\psi_j\right)\, \mathrm{d}^3x = \sum_{ij} a_i^*a_j H_{ij} $$

So the overall bond is written as a sum of all possible individual bonds just as in Lewis resonance the overall structure is written as a sum of all possible structures, hence the name *resonance*.

I did say it wasn't very interesting ...